# Incorrect syntax near 'Make'

Tags: c#, sql

```
namespace HondaDealership.Pages.Admin
```

{
[Authorize]
public class EditModel : PageModel
{

```
    public Car car = new Car();
    public string errorMessage = "";
    public string successMessage = "";

    public void OnGet()
    {
        string Id = Request.Query["Id"];

        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; database=HondaDealership;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM listCars WHERE Id=@Id";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            car.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            car.Make = reader.GetString(1);
                            car.CarModel = reader.GetString(2);
                            car.Year = reader.GetInt32(3);
                            car.Colour = reader.GetString(4);
                            car.Registration =  reader.GetString(5);
                            car.Price = reader.GetDecimal(6);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        car.Make = Request.Form["Make"];
        car.CarModel = Request.Form["CarModel"];
        car.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Year"]);
        car.Colour = Request.Form["Colour"];
        car.Registration = Request.Form["Registration"];
        car.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["Price"]);
        car.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Id"]);

        if (car.Make.Length == 0 || car.CarModel.Length == 0 ||
            car.Year <= 0 || car.Colour.Length == 0 ||
            car.Registration.Length == 0 || car.Price <= 0)
        {
            errorMessage = "All the fields are required";
            return;
        }


        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; database=HondaDealership;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "UPDATE listCars" +
                             "SET Make=@Make, CarModel=@CarModel, Year=@Year, Colour=@Colour, Registration=@Registration, Price=@Price" + 
                             "WHERE Id=@Id";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", car.Id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", car.Make);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarModel", car.CarModel);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", car.Year);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Colour", car.Colour);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registration", car.Registration);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", car.Price);


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            return;
        }

        Response.Redirect("/Admin/InStockCarsAdmin");
    }
}
```

}

The edit page populates, but when I hit 'Submit' It brings up the Error "incorrect syntax near 'Make'. When I put a breakpoint on the command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Make", car.Make); it has the correct value of "Honda".

The start of the HTML form is:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.car.Id" />
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="row mb-3"></label>
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Make</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Make" value="@Model.car.Make" />
        </div>
</div>
```

This is the table in the sql database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[listCars] (
[Id]           INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Make]         NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[CarModel]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[Year]         INT             NOT NULL,
[Colour]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[Registration] NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[Price]        DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_listCars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

I have looked over this and tried to find solutions for hours with no luck.

Comment: Do not use [AddwithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Side note, do your string values all potentially exceed 8000 characters?

Comment: How is the code written without using AddWithValue? Because it brings up the error sqlcommand.parameters cannot be used like a method when it is taken away.

Comment: Typo: Your sql will end up as `UPDATE listCarsSET Make=@Make ...`

Comment: No, they don't exceed 8000 characters.

Comment: Indeed, so why use `(max)`? This just creates unecessary overhead; likewise Price *probably* doesn't need have 16 digits

Comment: This table was autogenerated with migration.

Comment: *autogenerated* - and while having things done automagically might be quick in the short term, long term that is costing you database performance; best practice is to *always* specify data types and not rely on the (have to cope with the worst case) .net defaults

Comment: Consider using a verbatim string, starting with `@` then you can embed newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sql = "UPDATE listCars" +
             " SET Make=@Make, CarModel=@CarModel, Year=@Year, Colour=@Colour, Registration=@Registration, Price=@Price" + 
             " WHERE Id=@Id";
```

You missed a space between the table name and `SET`, the same goes for `WHERE`.